# how to automatically load user-defined functions in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a bunch of user-defined functions that are frequently used in mathematica. I wonder if I can store them in separate files and mathematica will load them on start and treat them as built-in functions, so that I don't have to repeat the definitions whenever I create a new .nb file. Something similar to functions in Matlab...

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a package in $UserBaseDirectory/Autoload.  This will be loaded at Kernel initialization time.

Your package should have a Kernel/init.m file

> MyPackage/Kernel/init.m

Reference documentation on Mathematica packages:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpMathematicaPackages.html

`DeclarePackage[]` is a lazy loading mechanism for symbols and their definitions.  The associated package is loaded only when the symbol is used:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeclarePackage.html

Comment: Hi Joshua, we have a proposal for a [separate Mathematica site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica?referrer=hWeRiD9Qz0oIDM_9uBjtlA2) under the SE network, for anything related to mma (not just programming questions like on SO). We're very close to launching (24 users remaining) and it would be great if you could commit to that proposal :)